# String interning in python with special character

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, string-interning

I understand that python internally using the string interning concept to map same string in a particular memory location, and that helps in a way to optimise the memory.

```
>>> a = 'a'
>>> id(a)
>>> 4503208208
>>> b = 'a'
>>> id(b)
>>> 4503208208
```

But why does special character in a string is handled differently

```
>>> i = 'a.'
>>> id(i)
>>> 4519365240
>>> j='a.'
>>> id(j)
>>> 4519463824
```

Why is the same logic and principle not implemented when there is a special character in the string?

Comment: I believe this is implementation specific

Comment: But why is that decision taken? There must be a reason for this implementation

Comment: [Here](http://guilload.com/python-string-interning/).

Comment: @ArghyaSaha At some point, the cost of determining if two strings are in fact identical outweighs the benefit of interning.

Comment: @ArghyaSaha short strings (of length zero and one) are, in fact, interned by design in the default 3.x CPython implementation. See e.g. the source code [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/bytesobject.c#L101).

Comment: @chepner can you please elaborate on it?